# Deploy BIRT report to a Knowage 8 Server

Tags: report, publish, birt, knowage

as suggested by Knowage itsself, since version 8 I use BIRT report designer instead of Knowage Report Designer in order to create my custom reports.
But, in Knowage Report Designer a "Publish" functionality is provided in order to deploy report to the Knowage Server
How can I deploy my reports using BIRT Report Designer to a Knowage 8 server? In fact, This functionality doesn't exist in BIRT
I'm just looking for Publish functionality in Birt Report Designer without success

Thanks a lot in advance for any hint